Addon UI with repeating "invoke_props_dialog" panel
For an add-on which creates a mesh object i am looking for a solution which repeats the "invoke_props_dialog" window each time the "OK" button is pressed:

With this dialog window the "execute" function is executed (creates the mesh object) only after the OK button is pressed:
However, after the OK button is pressed on the first dialog window, the next window does not have the OK button and now each time an input field change executes the "execute" function (so recreates the mesh object):

The final add-on version will create complex mesh objects with many input fields and re-creating the mesh object (takes a long time) after each input field change is unworkable.
Below the simple add-on code i used to test the add-on UI (ready to run in the text editor):
bl_info = {
    "name": "Orbitals",
    "author": "Multiple Authors",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (4, 2, 0),
    "location": "Add > Mesh > Orbitals",
    "description": "Orbitals",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Simulation",
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,IntProperty,FloatProperty,BoolProperty)

class VIEW_MT_orbitals_menu_add(Menu):
    # Define the "Orbitals" menu
    bl_idname = "V_MT_Orbitals"
    bl_label = "Orbitals"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN'
        layout.operator("mesh.orbitals",text="Orbitals")

# Register all operators and panels

class VIEW_MT_orbitals_input(Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.orbitals"
    bl_label = "Orbitals"
    bl_description = ("Orbitals")
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO','PRESET'}

    v: IntProperty(
                name="Vertices v",
                description="Vertices v",
                min=1,
                max=1000,
                default=32
                )
    r: FloatProperty(
                name="Radius r",
                description="Radius r",
                min=0.001,
                max=100,
                default=1
                )


    # Display the options
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("wm.operator_defaults")
        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'

        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text="Input")
        col = box.column(align=True)
        col.prop(self, "v")
        col.prop(self, "r")

    def invoke(self,context,event):
#        return self.execute(context)
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
#        return context.window_manager.invoke_confirm(self, event)
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=self.v, radius=self.r, 
        enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))


        return {'FINISHED'}

# Define "Extras" menu
def menu_func(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN'
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator("mesh.orbitals",
                    text="Orbitals", icon="PACKAGE")

# Register
classes = [VIEW_MT_orbitals_menu_add,VIEW_MT_orbitals_input]

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    # Add "Extras" menu to the "Add Mesh" menu 
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    # Remove "Extras" menu from the "Add Mesh" menu 
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)

    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Any idea how to repeat the window with the OK button?
